# React/Webpack applying styles to tags but not classes/ids

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have setup my own react project from some tutorials including my own webpack configuration. When I try to style elements it is able to apply style to generic html tags such as `<body>` or `<p>` but it fails when I try to style classes/ids.

I know my css file is being imported because it styles the generic tags.

Webpack Config

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        "style-loader",
        {
            loader:"css-loader",
            options:{
                modules:true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

CSS

```
.oakResults {
    font-size:20px;
}

#yoyoyo {
    color:red;
}

p {
    color:orange;
}
```

React

```
<div className='oakResults'>
    <p id='yoyoyo'>Results</p>
</div>
```

In my example, the `<p>` is colored red, but `.oakResults` font does not change and when I comment out the `<p>` style it doesn't turn red.

I want it to be able to style to both generic tags and classes/ids.

Comment: I need more details. Can you check in the inspect element if the oakResults style is being applied. Check what are applied. I'm thinking maybe it is being overwritten by other styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason of this issue is you have enable the [css modules in webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) but not referring the css correctly.

So if you don't need the css module, try to remove `options:{ modules:true}` from your webpack config. Then the css could be applied to the class name you set in ReactJS.

Or if you do need the css module, keep the Webpack config. But modify your ReactJS to something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from 'path\to\file.css';

class foo extend Component {
  render() {
    return (<div classname={styles.oakResults}> This is the test component</div>)
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this,

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
}
```

From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules),

> The modules option enables/disables the CSS Modules specification and setup basic behaviour.
>
> Using `false` value increase performance because we avoid parsing CSS Modules features, it will be useful for developers who use vanilla css or use other technologies.

Refer more about [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).